# libGDX can not see Android SDK

Tags: android, libgdx, android-sdk-tools

I am a newbie android develiper. I have just installed the most recent Android Studio and downloaded libGDX setup tool. However, when I try to generate a new project, it shows the error:

> Your Android SDK path doesn't contain an SDK! Please install the Android SDK, including all platforms and build tools!

I am pretty sure I have Android SDK installed and I put a correct location `C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`, because I copied it from Android studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is how](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-setup/src/com/badlogic/gdx/setup/GdxSetup.java) libGDX is checking if android SDK location valid:

```
public static boolean isSdkLocationValid (String sdkLocation) {
    return new File(sdkLocation, "tools").exists() && new File(sdkLocation, "platforms").exists();
}
```

However, I don't have tools folder in my setup. Probably, in fresh Android SDK it was renamed or I don't have required tools installed, not sure (pls suggest in comments). However, the workaround is to create an empty `tools` folder in `C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue to day. I think the problem is that the SDK that comes with Android Studio dos not contain the `"tools"` folder. You'll have to download it manually and add it to the SDK. Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools). I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot of questions similar to this and found the following information

"Where does Android Studio install sdk on Mac?
Configure Android SDK Variable In macOS.
Generally, the Android SDK is installed in the /Users/user-name/Library/Android/sdk folder on macOS."

https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-set-android-sdk-path-in-windows-and-mac/

In your "Android SDK: " area on libGDX you can type in the following path and just replace with your username

/Users/"user-name"/Library/Android/sdk